# pycharm scrolls tabs instead of document

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I have installed pycharm 125.92 openjdk 1.7.0_15 on ubuntu 12.10 x64
So, the problem is when i open document and try to scroll it, pycharm opens recent documents and scroll throughout them. Any suggestion why it happens?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101256). Follow YouTrack issue for updates.

**Workaround:**

> Create your own custom keymap from the default one (`File` | `Settings` | `Keymap`). Then delete mouse
>   shortcuts from `Main menu` | `Navigate` | **Back** / **Forward**, let
>   them be assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> only.

Answer (score 0):

And please use Oracle JRE instead of OpenJDK.
from: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html
"Oracle JRE 1.6+ (OpenJDK is not supported)"