# Strange IntelliJ Behaviour on Arrow Keys

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've upgraded to intelliJ 12 on OS X because of the Earthday deal they have going on, but I've encountered some incredibly annoying behaviour:

When editing a Scala file, pressing an arrow key will occasionally switch the editor tabs, which when typing is incredibly annoying.

I've tried to Google for this problem, but not found anything.

Comment: `Alt` + left/right arrow switches tabs. Maybe you somehow accidentally hit `Alt`?

Comment: I can't remember which bindings I changed and which are different on Macs, but for me it's CTRL-LEFT and CTRL-RIGHT that switch tabs.

Comment: @ghik it doesn't on the OS X version.

Comment: It may be caused by the [touchpad actions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766581/104891).

Comment: @Michael Yes, it does! I have a Mac, and I use Alt+L/R all the time to switch between tabs.